# Select row in group with largest value in particular column postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a database table which looks like this.

```
 id       account_id      action             time_point

 3        234            delete                100
 1        656            create                600
 1        4435           update                900
 3        645            create                50
```

I need to group this table by id and select particular row where time_point has a largest value.

Result table should look like this:

```
 id       account_id      action             time_point

 3        234            delete                100
 1        4435           update                900
```

Thanks for help,
qwew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on` to solve this top 1 per group problem:

```
select distinct on (id) *
from mytable
order by id, time_point desc
```

However, this does not allow possible to ties. If so, `rank()` is a better solution:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by id order by time_point desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Or, if you are running Postgres 13:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by rank() over(partition by id order by time_point desc)
fetch first row with ties
```

Answer (score 1):

check this.

```
select * from x
where exists (
  select 1 from x xin
  where xin.id = x.id 
  having max(time_point) = time_point
);
```